# My Pi and external hard drive only connects occasionally (other linux machine can read it)

Tags: raspbian, hard-drive

I want to attach [a 2x2.5 external drive](http://www.deltaco.eu/en/product/(MAP-GD18U)/Deltaco-MAP-GD18U---Storage-enclosure---25---SATA-3Gb-s---300-MBps---RAID-0-1---USB-30---black/) to my RPi (Raspbian, kernel release 3.12.32+), but I cannot get the RPi to be consistently accepted by the system. It sometimes works, but more often not. The drive works when I plug it into my HTPC (running XBMCbuntu): everything can then be seen and read (i.e. watched), and the internal drives in the enclosure are tested and ok.

- The only pattern I have found is that once I am able to mount the
  drive, I can then reboot the Pi and everything works, over and over again;
  but when it does not work, I have no sure way of getting it work. (If I, for example, detach the drive and then try to attach it again.)
- I have tried, without noticing any pattern: (1) starting the Pi and then attaching the drive, (2) starting them all at the same time, (3) first powering on the drive and then the Pi.
- The external drive is getting power separately, as is my Pi, so it should not be a power issue. I mainly use an external USB hub for the connection, but I have tested to put the drive directly to the pi as well (stil with external power to the drive, of course).
- The enclosure uses a SATA to USB bridge, since it is connecting two 2.5 inch drives into one usb cable.

**Unsuccessful attachment**: When it does not attach to the Pi, dmesg gives me info such as "scsi 0:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery", or, in another try "smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: hardware isn't capable of remote wakeup". Here is one example of the former:

```
    pi@raspberrypi /mnt $ dmesg | tail -32
    [ 1570.033277] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 4 using dwc_otg
    [ 1570.201161] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=067b, idProduct=2775
    [ 1570.201195] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
    [ 1570.201211] usb 1-1.2: Product: USB-SATA Bridge
    [ 1570.201225] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Prolific Technology Inc.
    [ 1570.201238] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: PROLIFICMP00000000F
    [ 1570.209010] usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
    [ 1570.223282] scsi0 : usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0
    [ 1592.354652] usb 1-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 4 using dwc_otg
    [ 1592.604664] usb 1-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 4 using dwc_otg
    [ 1592.684673] usb 1-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
    [ 1592.874701] usb 1-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
    [ 1593.064742] usb 1-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 4 using dwc_otg
    [ 1593.144723] usb 1-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
    [ 1593.334708] usb 1-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
    [ 1593.524722] usb 1-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 4 using dwc_otg
    [ 1593.944658] usb 1-1.2: device not accepting address 4, error -71
    [ 1594.024771] usb 1-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 4 using dwc_otg
    [ 1594.444638] usb 1-1.2: device not accepting address 4, error -71
    [ 1594.445175] scsi 0:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
    [ 1594.445413] usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 4
    [ 1594.524801] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 5 using dwc_otg
    [ 1594.604779] usb 1-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
    [ 1594.794822] usb 1-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
    [ 1594.984809] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 6 using dwc_otg
    [ 1595.064817] usb 1-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
    [ 1595.254819] usb 1-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
    [ 1595.444846] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 7 using dwc_otg
    [ 1595.864773] usb 1-1.2: device not accepting address 7, error -71
    [ 1595.944911] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 8 using dwc_otg
    [ 1596.364814] usb 1-1.2: device not accepting address 8, error -71
    [ 1596.365038] hub 1-1:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
    pi@raspberrypi /mnt $
```

**Successful attachment**: The minority of time when it does attach, it looks like this:

```
[  359.779760] usb 1-1.2.2: new high-speed USB device number 7 using dwc_otg
[  359.947529] usb 1-1.2.2: New USB device found, idVendor=067b, idProduct=2775
[  359.947565] usb 1-1.2.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  359.947582] usb 1-1.2.2: Product: USB-SATA Bridge
[  359.947597] usb 1-1.2.2: Manufacturer: Prolific Technology Inc.
[  359.947611] usb 1-1.2.2: SerialNumber: PROLIFICMP00000000F
[  359.955142] usb-storage 1-1.2.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  359.960274] scsi1 : usb-storage 1-1.2.2:1.0
[  365.479085] scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WDC WD10 JUCT-73J6SY0     01.0 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
[  365.484118] sd 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[  365.485031] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] 1953525168 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/931 GiB)
[  365.485766] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[  365.485803] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
[  365.486548] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] No Caching mode page found
[  365.486582] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  365.491100] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] No Caching mode page found
[  365.491138] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  365.492062] scsi 1:0:0:1: Direct-Access     ST2000LM 003 HN-M201RAD   2BC1 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
[  365.495593] sd 1:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[  365.498429]  sda: sda1
[  365.502077] sd 1:0:0:1: [sdb] 3907029168 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 TB/1.81 TiB)
[  365.503132] sd 1:0:0:1: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[  365.503169] sd 1:0:0:1: [sdb] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
[  365.504207] sd 1:0:0:1: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[  365.504241] sd 1:0:0:1: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  365.507552] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] No Caching mode page found
[  365.507591] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  365.507613] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[  365.508952] sd 1:0:0:1: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[  365.508986] sd 1:0:0:1: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  365.521014]  sdb: sdb1
[  365.524448] sd 1:0:0:1: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[  365.524485] sd 1:0:0:1: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  365.524508] sd 1:0:0:1: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
```

Any help is much appreciated, I do not know where to start. It definitely seems to be something with the inability of the Pi to "tell" the drive what to do, but I have much to little knowledge of what is going on to have an idea of what to do.

[Modified the question 22 Nov, after some more testing]

Comment: Is the drive connected directly or via a hub?  Also, add the output of `uname -r` from both the pi *and* the XMBCbuntu machine.